# Reading and writing to a file inside a forEach only writing the last loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, fs

I have a forEach where I read and write data to a file, (don't want to change that to write all at once) but it's only writing the last loop, and before then it doesn't write anything. Note (combinedOutput) which I'm writing to the file, is changed each loop so it's only writing the last value of combinedOutput. What's going on? Do I need to close a file each time or something?

```
dev_users.forEach((user, i) => {
fs.readFile('name.json', function(err, data) {
      var json = JSON.parse(data);
      json.push(combinedOutput);

      fs.writeFile('name.json', JSON.stringify(json), (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, one code smell is that you are performing asynchronous logic in a synchronous forEach loop.

Comment: @Taplar Ahhh thank you!!!!!!! god that's dumb

Comment: Also, why are you reading and writing the same file over and over.  Just accumulate the data you want and write it all at once.

Comment: "*I don't want to change that to write all at once*" - well, that's precisely what you **should** do. Why wouldn't you want to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You are performing two asynchronous operations inside a loop so they will all be running in parallel and the last one to run will overwrite others.

I would suggest that you accumulate all the data you want to write first and then write it all at once in one read/write operation.

You seem to be appending a `combinedOutput` variable to the end of an array in each iteration of the loop, but you don't show where that variable comes from so we can't show full code for doing this, but the general code would look like this:

```
let newData = dev_users.map(user => {
    // create whatever new data you want here and return it
    return something;
});

fs.readFile('name.json', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
        return;
    }
    try {
        // add new data onto end of existing data
        let existingData = JSON.parse(data);
        existingData.push(...newData);
        fs.writeFile('name.json', JSON.stringify(existingData), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                // handler error
            } else {
                // all done successfully
            }
        });
    } catch(e) {
        // handle error
        return;
    }
});
```

Using the promise interface for reading and writing the file, this would be a bit simpler:

```
async function writeMyData(dev_users) {
    let newData = dev_users.map(user => {
        // create whatever new data you want here and return it
        return something;
    });
    let existingData = JSON.parse(await fs.promises.readFile('name.json'));
    existingData.push(...newData);
    return fs.promises.writeFile('name.json', JSON.stringify(existingData));
}

writeMyData(dev_users).then(() => {
    console.log("finished successfully");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```